# Track and sum manual edits on Google Sheets

Tags: html, google-sheets, google-analytics-api

I am looking to analyze some Google Speech-to-cloud transcripts. Essentially I have a spreadsheet of before the transcript was edited and also a separate transcript of after the transcript was edited.

I've been tracking period additions and added columns, but I would really like to be able to track word changes and total number of edits.

It appears google does keep record of this on the back end since when you go into edit history you can view every single change that occurred.

I would love to be able to mine that version history data in a way that I can report on the total number of edits, the total number of word changes, and the total number of added words. I'm not sure what the first steps would be to do something like this. Any guidance or advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Further, please read the [Stack Overflow question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist). Also learn how to post [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Hi ! So you basically want to compare the data of **two different Spreadsheets** am I right? Are you open to suggestions using [Apps Scripts](https://developers.google.com/apps-script) ?

Comment: Hi Mateo, yes! I myself don't actually know how to use Apps Scripts but I may be able to help navigate the problem and find someone who can.

Comment: **So just to clarify, you basically want to: get two versions of two different spreadsheets and compare them, am I right?** To get different versions of a spreadsheet, when you said *"mine the version history data"* you can access this version history and make a copy of past edits doing the following : **File->Version History->See version history** and in the version history pannel navigate to the version you want to extract the data and on its 3 dots for editing select **Make a copy**. In this way you can extract past data without altering the current spreadsheet state.